# how do I make Vuetify carousel images responsive especially on mobile screens?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slider, vuetify.js, carousel

I also tried effecting this with CSS but seems not to be working, I am aware Vuetify carousels are not quite responsive but I feel the Veutify team should have addressed such issue by now or is there a better way to achieve this?

```
 <v-flex xs12 md8  lg6 >
             <v-carousel  style="border-radius:4px; "  height="400px" class="slides">
        <v-carousel-item
          class="slides"
          v-for="(item,i) in items"
          :key="i"
          :src="item.src"
          reverse-transition="fade-transition"
          transition="fade-transition" 
          
          >
          </v-carousel-item>
      </v-carousel>
          </v-flex>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuetify carousel is honestly an awful carousel component

I can't count the amount of people I've seen complain about its lack of responsiveness

There's no "Vuetify" way of doing what you want to do and you can't use `<v-responsive>` to fix which leaves you with two main options:

1. Use a different component for a carousel. Vuetify tree shakes so you're not wasting/saving any bundle size by using or not using it. You can use a dedicated carousel plugin that's a lot more powerful, flexible and actually works properly on mobile. This is the option I suggest.
2. Write a fair amount of custom CSS to overwrite parts of the component itself.

Unfortunately there's not too much better of a solution. I always advocate for just using a superior carousel component!

Comment: Thanks Jordan for your response, I really appreciate.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't give you a better answer. There is a lot of really good carousel components out there so you can't really go wrong. I have no idea why Vuetify isn't improving that component. Make sure to mark the answer as correct if you think it's helpful so it gets a bit more visibility!  :) Good luck!